# How to create a group in the UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have implemented an UIAlertController (currently using the [XLActionController](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController)) with the look and feel as the builtin menu from the iOS Contacts app (see pictures below).

I want to add a submenu which "folds out" just like in the Contacts app (see picture 2)

The builtin Contacts app (see pictures) has a menu which contains a "group" which opens (animates) when clicked - revealing the siblings as showin in the second picture. When the header is clicked it closes (animates) and returns like shows in the first picture. (The below can be achieved installing a supported app like Skype for Business)

Is this possible to build using either the default UIAlertController or eg XLActionController

[image: AlertController in Contacts]

Comment: you need to create custom one .. using UITableView

Answer (score 0):

*This answer does not solve your problem but it may help you find a solution.*

---

- You need to build a custom view controller transitions and presentations. Your viewController must be a subclass of `UIPresentationController`. Have a look at this tutorial.

  [UIPresentationController Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3636807-uipresentationcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)
- You can use also a simple `UIView` which contains a `UITableView` that you animate upwards/downwards. Have a look at this tutorial

[How to Create a Slide-In Menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kwCfFG5fDA)